# Search through a 3d list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int index;
}
```

and if I have a `List<List<List<myStruct>>> lists`

Is there a way to

1) obtain all elements that have `myStruct.index = 0`

2) ensure that the ordering is in place? (e.g. `lists[0][j][k]` will always come before `lists[1][j][k]` in the result).

I have tried using something like `lists.FindAll(x=>...)` format, but i could not figure out how to express it for lists bigger than 1D, and also that i am unsure of the resultant ordering.

Comment: What means "obtain all elements"? In general most LINQ methods keep the original order and it's also stable which means that it preserves the order of elements that are equal.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I meant obtaining all struct myStruct in lists that fulfills the condition myStruct.index = 0

Comment: still not clear, your result is a `List<myStruct>`?

Comment: Something like `lists.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y)).Where(a => a.index == 0)`?

Comment: @juharr Something like that; but i was wondering if there is a way to keep the original ordering consistent.

Comment: @JohnTan That will keep them in order.  Do you mean you also need the indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu could use `SelectMany` and flatten the list

```
lists.SelectMany(x=>x.SelectMany(s=>s))
     .Where(x=>x.index ==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            List<List<List<myStruct>>> data = new List<List<List<myStruct>>>();
            var results = data.Select((x, i) => x.Select((y, j) => y.Select((z, k) => new
            {
                i = i,
                j = j,
                k = k,
                z = z
            })));
```

Comment: First you're not doing the filtering that the OP wanted.  Second it would be better to flatten this with 2 `SelectMany` calls so you would end up with a `IEnumerable<myStruct>` instead of an `IEnumerable<IEnumerabl<IEnumerable<myStruct>>>`.

Comment: The op said :  ensure that the ordering is in place.  Select Many will not keep structure.

Answer (score 0):

I never find `SelectMany` is easy to read. What about

```
(from l1 in lists
from l2 in l1
from x in l2
where x.index == 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to flatten this with SelectMany, then use a simple Where clause;

```
 list3d
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .SelectMany(y => y)
    .SelectMany(z => z)
    .Where(item => <your condition here>);
```

`SelectMany` takes one sequence (like your `List<List<List<T>>>`), converts each one to a sequence, and then flattens down all of those into one big sequence. So you are looking to flatten down your 3d list onto a single sequence, and then just treat it as a straightforward filter.